# Inverted list like structure in latex using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help in drawing this kind of structure using latex? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Se. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to draw two tables, with some content, and with arrows connected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @MS-SPO, Yes exactly!

Answer (score 3):

An idea to start with:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node (A) at (1.5, 5.5) {};
        \node (B) at (1.5, 4.5) {};
        \node (C) at (1.5, 3.5) {};
        \node (D) at (1.5, 2.5) {};
        \node (E) at (1.5, 1.5) {};
        \node (F) at (1.5, 0.5) {};
        \node (G) at (1.5, -0.5){};
        
        \node (A1) at (4.5, 6.5) {A};
        \node (B1) at (4.5, 5.5) {B};
        \node (C1) at (4.5, 4.5) {C};
        \node (D1) at (4.5, 3.5) {D};
        \node (E1) at (4.5, 2.5) {E};
        \node (F1) at (4.5, 1.5) {F};
        \node (G1) at (4.5, 0.5) {G};
    
        \draw[->,dashed]
        (A) edge[bend left]  (A1)
        (B) edge[bend left]  (B1)
        (C) edge[bend left]  (C1)
        (D) edge[bend left]  (D1)
        (E) edge[bend left]  (E1)
        (F) edge[bend left]  (F1)
        (G) edge[bend left]  (G1);
        
        
        
        \draw[shift={(0,-1)}] (0,0) grid (2,8);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} {
        \fill (1.5,\x-0.5) circle(0.2);
        }

        \draw[shift={(4,0)}] (0,0) grid (4,8);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5} {
        }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @roland. This helped! :)